How do you incorporate NOT BLANK in a IF function with two conditions
First timer here so please go easy on me.
I have 2 columns. Column A has only True or False values whereas Column B has different dates and some cells are blanks.
In column C, I want to add a Function which looks at column A first and if it is True in Column A then i want "YES" in column C and if False in column A then i want the formula to look at Column B for any cells that are "NOT BLANK" in which case it should return a YES in column C. If column A is false and column B is blank then i want "NO" in column C.
I hope it makes sense. Please let me know if you need any further details.
Thanks.
I have tried IFs with NOT and ISBLANK but cant seem to get it to work but i know Im not great at complicated IF functions so i must be missing something quite obvious somewhere

You can use an OR() formula for your two tests inside the IF(). This would look something like: =if(OR(A1, B1<>""), "Yes", "No")

Please add samples of data with expected result.

remember a cell with a formula that is displaying "", or if your number style is set to display blank for certain values, or if a cell has spaces or non visible characters, they are not blank cells for the ISBLANK function.

Thank you for your response, all but the above suggestions havent worked.  Are you able to advise how i add my sample of data here. I cannot see anywhere to upload a screenshot. When i copy the data here in the comment box, becomes very messy. Some of the forumlas i have also tried are:=IF(AND(A2="FALSE",B2=""),"NO","YES")      &      =IF(OR(A2="TRUE",B2<>""),"Yes","No")      but they dont seem to give me the desired results. I will try to see if i can upload my excel data here somehow.

I have tried to copy the data in the below box where there are 4 columns, first one assume column A named Plan cancelled, then column B is Member cancelled, the col C should be Cancelled (YES/NO) which should contain the formula and the 4th column i have added Notes for you to understand the reason behind YES and NO in column C. Please note some of the spaced out col B represents blank cells.. Hope this helps.

Plan cancelled - member cancelled    -    Cancelled (YES?NO)-   NOTES
FALSE          - 25/11/2020 15:00     -    YES                    -  YES because column B is not blank
FALSE   -                                   -   NO                            - NO because column A is False and B is blank
TRUE           - 12/02/2021 16:16     -    YES                           - YES bcause column A is TRUE
TRUE           -                                -  YES                      - YES bcause column A is TRUE and B is blank

I have just realised the format after submitting the comment that it is unreadable so please advise if there is another way of sharing the data

@JNevill Column A has values True or False and the 1st condition should be if A is TRUE then return Yes otherwise look at B and if not Blank then return Yes and if none of the 2 conditions meet then return No

If the values in A are the string literals "TRUE" and "FALSE" and not an actual boolean (Yes/No, 1/0, True/False) then you will have to add the whole condition =IF(OR(A1="TRUE", B1<>""), "Yes","No") at any rate, the logic is identical. You want a "YES" in the event that A1 is True OR B1 is blank, so employing the OR() formula inside the IF() condition parameter is the right solution.

Thanks @JNevill - I have tried this IF with OR like i mentioned in my previous post it seems to be only working on the 2nd condition and does not do do anything for the 1st condition e.g. I would expect to see Yes in all fields if i filter col A on True but i can see it shows Yes and No in different fields in col C. Am i missing something?

So do something about that. What does =A1="True" return? What does =A1=True return? Does it return the right true/false value you expect? If not, why? I can't see your workbook. I can't see the values in column A. You'll have to write the condition that works for your data.

Just tried it and without quotes it works but with quotes it gives the incorrect result. I have managed to find the answer on another platform as it was easy to share my sample data there. The issue was the boolean variables which is new to me. Thanks for looking.
